# onStop being called after onDestroy?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle

I've encountered a rather strange issue with `Activity` lifecycle.

**Short prequel:**

The first symptom that I've found is that it crashed with `IllegalArgumentException` when I was trying to unregister receiver in `onStop` after registering it in `onStart`.

After dumping the full list of active receivers (some reflection magic), I've found that my receiver is not the list. It was either being removed somewhere else by mistake, or it was removed during `onDestroy` call of `Activity` where `Context` is being cleaned (during `onDestroy` `ActivityThread` calls `ContextImpl#performFinalCleanup`, which then calls `LoadedApk#removeContextRegistrations`).

**What is happening?**

After adding some more analytics info to the crash, I found out that while the crash is happening in `onStop`, the `Activity` is in a pretty weird state - it's `isDestroyed()` call returns `true`, it's `isFinishing()` returns `false`, and it's `getLifecycle().getCurrentState()` returns `DESTROYED`...

Checking normal `onStop()` (without crash) call shows that the `Activity` is in this state:

`isDestroyed()` is `false`, and `getLifecycle().getCurrentState()` is `CREATED` in `onStop`.

So I drew the conclusion that `onStop` is being called after `onDestroy`, which I thought is impossible, but it seems to happen.

And `onStop` is definitely not being called manually by something else in the app, since this is the stack trace of where the `onStop` is called from.

```java
com.myapp.TheActivity.onStop (TheActivity.java:217)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop (Instrumentation.java:1474)
android.app.Activity.performStop (Activity.java:8189)
android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop (ActivityThread.java:4994)
android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner (ActivityThread.java:4967)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity (ActivityThread.java:5047)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:233)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:201)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:173)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2220)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8016)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Comment: That _is_ a rather strange issue.  Does it happen only on certain devices?

Comment: @RyanM if only! So far I've seen Sony, Samsung, Google Pixel 4, Huawei devices...

Answer (score 2):

The reason is unclear, but, it is getting more and more attention recently. And it happens in both onResume/onPause and onStart/onStop pairs to call register/unregister. About those lifeCycle checks, make sure you have on Instance of the activity with hashCode() or something. Anyway, to fix the issue the best practice is to wrap register/unregister calls in try/catch block:

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    try {
        appUpdateReceiver = new AppUpdateReceiver();
        registerReceiver(appUpdateReceiver, appUpdateIntentFilter);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // already registered
    }

}

private void unregisterBroadcastReceiver() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(appUpdateReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // already unregistered
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood that correctly, you also see the similar behavior in your app?

Comment: Hey man. I was involved in your previous question too. I see you are still looking for the reason. I admire that, but, I just want to know if try/catch block fixes the problem. Have you checked that?

Comment: Well, for the lack of better solution I did wrap it in a try-catch even before I've asked the first question, and every time I catch it, I report is as non-fatal to Crashlytics. While it fixes the crash, it does not fix the underlying issue - I still see it happening for some users. And I'm really itching to understand what can cause such a weird behavior, because there may or may not be a couple of other places in the app I'm writing that face same weird lifecycle issues.

Comment: Just noting here, the "register" call and trying to catch with `IllegalArgumentException` will not work if it was registered before, it will only register a duplicate of the receiver. I'd suggest using a boolean variable for that, even though it's just a sample code. For unregistering, it does work so no changes are required there.

Comment: You can't register a duplicate of a receiver from same context, it throws the IllegalArgumentException which is the idea of the try/catch block. Although saving the flag in a boolean should be an OK implementation too, I remember Alexander had a problem with saving the flag in a boolean which he'd mentioned on this subject in another question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure why that happens in the first place, but I've encountered something similar on one of the Xiaomi devices that did not happen on any of the emulators (or my device), but happened on somebody else's phone. `onStop()` was called 5 seconds after the app was moved to background, but `onPause()` was called immediately. More weird issue, if in between these 5 seconds, I open the app from task manager, `onStart()` was called. (Notice the 2 `onStart()` calls but not a singular `onStop()` call.) I think it would have been possible if the activity was destroyed, `onDestroy()` would be called before `onStop()`. As an alternative, you might try to move the receiver registration calls to `onResume()` and `onPause()` instead of `onStart()` and `onStop()`.

Second: I don't exactly use lifecycle of the activity when it comes to checking resumed or paused state, but I'd suggest overriding all of those methods (onPause, onResume etc...), storing the state on boolean variables and logging the state while checking the actual calls. Maybe that will result in a different state since this is a pretty unusual check.

If it does not happen on other activities, in that activity, maybe something is posting so many callbacks to the main message looper that prevents `onStop()` from getting called in the first place because of the overflow, causing this exception to happen. These are only assumptions, of course, but I'd be grateful if they helped in a way.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the exact question, it shows that on some devices it also happens for some reason. Though I've also seen it on normal devices, like Pixel 4, which aren't really known to play tricks like that. I guess you deserve the bounty for at least giving me hope that maybe I will meet someone with same issue, ha-ha :)

Comment: The world of Android phones is a really weird one not gonna lie, the most unexpected stuff happens on production, such as your issue or the one I encountered. Nevertheless, thanks for the bounty! Hopefully changing to this way will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Furkan You say onStart was called 2 times but onStop once. The second onStart belongs to a new activity object. Nothing wierd about that. I suggest to add hashCode so you don't get confused over normal stuff. In case of this issue, there is no difference between onStart/onStop and onResume/onPause. The issue happens with both. Btw, about that 5 second delay story, it causes so obvious problems in the user experience that there is no chance Xiaomi QA allow such phone enters market. Maybe there was a problem on that particular device.

Comment: @Sina I am entirely sure the calls belonged to the same activity because I've checked the object address hash from the debugger which was the same, plus, there were no orientation changes and the activity had "android:configChanges" attributes all over the place. I also said "onStart is called twice but onStop wasn't called even once".

Comment: Very interesting!